# C# filepath to Excel file in solution or bin/debug folder?

Tags: c#, path, openfiledialog

I am trying to reach an Excel file withouth specifying the whole absolute path on my pc.

In stead of this:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Workbook sheet = app.Workbooks.Open(ofd.FileName);
           //etc
        }
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.ShowDialog();
string name = sfd.FileName;
sheet.SaveAs(name);
```

I would like to always use the template provided in the solution, dynamically.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, you said you don't want to use the absolute path on your PC but nowhere in your code did you use such thing. In your code you're using an `OpenFileDialog` to get the path of the filename. You said you'd liked to use the template? provided in the solution? what template or solution are you talking abou?

Comment: I am sorry. What I am doing now is let the user specify the excel template to use for the program to insert data in. What I want is not to use OpenFileDialog() so the program always loads a template from the same location within to solution. I know i can hardcode the location of the file, but that wouldn't work on other pc's. So i want to dynamically get the file no matter which pc the program is running on.

Comment: Read/Write data files for your application should be stored in the folder described by Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData. This folder is retrieved with Environment.GetFolder method. Here you create a subfolder for your application to store and retrieve your files.

Comment: var fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), @"etiketten.xlsx");

Did the trick

Comment: Do not save user data in `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly‌​().Location`; most users can't write there and this folder can be replaced if the user uninstalls or repairs the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if you want to get a file from your application's directory use this,

```
 Excel.Workbook sheet = app.Workbooks.Open(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ExcelFile.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually was:

Excel.Workbook sheet = app.Workbooks.Open(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ExcelFile.xlsx");

Without the parantheses but that worked!

Comment: @JohnDorian ah my bad, copy pasted that from a vb.net app.